# mysql_result into more advanceed mysqli function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am upgrading my small project from `MYSQL` database into `MYSQLi` and I have only 3 functions left to update.

This is my function in `MYSQL`:

```
function id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize ($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT ´id´ FROM ´members´ WHERE ´username´ = '$username'"), 0, 'id');
}
```

I have this code which I tried to migrate into the function above but no use:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM `settings`";
 if (!$row = $db_connect->query($result)) {
     die('Oops, something went wrong during loading data! Error x010');
 }
```

I know I am supposed to public the code I tried out, but the problem is I do not really know how to migrate the `MYSQLi` into just that specific function and I know that the code was wrong in all ways possible if so to say.

Comment: there is nothing specific in this function

Comment: @YourCommonSense well maybe not I'm just here and there, because I tryed to migrate the codes together with no luck

Comment: you're assuming that SELECT query succeeded, and blindly pass the return value to a fetch function. Not a good idea. Never EVER assume a db operation succeeded.

Comment: Give some slack… At least the OP is moving in the right direction, i.e. from `mysql_*` to `mysqli`.

Comment: mysqli doesn't have an equivalent of `mysql_result()`. you'll have to fetch a row and extract your field from that.

Comment: @MarcB I don't know if I did understand you right but here is how it works, the function is only running once when another operation succeed. Is it still wrong?

Comment: @drikane: pretend that something went wrong and your db server failed. now mysql_query() will return a boolean false to indicate failure, instead of a result handle. mysql_fetch will take that boolean false and try to fetch.. but can't, since it's not a result. now you get the "boolean provided" error.

Comment: @MarcB Ok good to know thank you, the way you described ´"you'll have to fetch a row and extract your field from that."´ I think I tryed that somehow out but with no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right answer, the code should be following:

```
function id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    global $db_connect;

    $result = $db_connect->query("SELECT(id) FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
    if (false === $result) {
        return false;
    }
    return ($result->num_rows === 1);
}
```

It's simple and I still can stick to my code without integrating other scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this one to migrate:
https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php

First, connect somewhere earlier in the script:

```
include 'safemysql.class.php';
$opts = array(
    'user'    => 'user',
    'pass'    => 'pass',
    'db'      => 'db',
    'charset' => 'latin1',
);
$db = new SafeMySQL($opts);
```

then write your function this way

```
function id_from_username($username) 
{
    global $db;
    return $db->getOne("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ?s", $username);
}
```

note that this is not a pure mysqli but a custom library built upon it.
Most important difference is that every placeholder have to be marked with it's type, according to their role in the query. E.g. for the string `$username` string placeholder (`?s`) were used.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I still would stick to my code but if I won't figure out anything I'll try code above :)